# How to make CMD+delete delete a line (left of the cursor) in Firefox

Tags: macos, firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

I recently switched from Chrome to Firefox (OS X version 5.0.1) and I'm surprised to see that <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd> is not working.

When I hit <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd> in any editor (as well as Chrome and Safari), the line left of the cursor is deleted.  This unfortunately doesn't work on Firefox.  Is there a way to enable it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>Cmd-Delete</kbd> works in the newest version of Firefox and Chrome, since they both respect macOS keyboard shortcuts now.

The old Bash shortcut <kbd>Ctrl-U</kbd> does not work in these browsers anymore. It does, however, work in a Terminal.

Comment: Yeah, it's kind of hard to explain.. and unfortunately very application specific.

Comment: AFAIK, Firefox uses `Ctlr` + `U` for view source.

Comment: @ChenLevy On Windows, I guess. This question is about OS X / macOS. But ever since posting the answer, Firefox have adopted the standard OS X shorcuts.